# How do I change the brightness for particles in a SCNParticleSystem?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, metal

I have been trying to adjust the brightness of the particles in a SCNParticleSystem, but have not been able to find a way to do it.  I have found a way to change the variation in brightness with particleColorVariation, but this does not achieve the effect I am looking for.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I knew I would get it as soon as I posted.  The problem was solved by doubling the intensity setting.

Answer (score 1):

> **You can do it via `particleColor` instance property that changes the color of newly spawned particles**. Blend mode must be `alpha`.

Test it with my code:

```
let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
particleSystem.birthRate = 300
particleSystem.particleSize = 0.025

particleSystem.particleColor = UIColor(hue: 0.57, 
                                saturation: 0.87, 
                                brightness: 0.92,    // USE THIS PROPERTY
                                     alpha: 1)
particleSystem.blendMode = .alpha
particleSystem.emittingDirection = .init(1,1,1)
particleSystem.emitterShape = .init(SCNSphere(radius: 3))
particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 0.5

let particlesNode = SCNNode()
particlesNode.position = SCNVector3(0,3,0)
particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)
```